# How to close a background android app programmatically in Unity

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to force close some background Android apps by package name using Unity, but I can't figure out the correct way to do it via the Android API.

I have used several functions from the Android API, but none of them seem to work. Here's how I initialize the Java class.

```
 AndroidJavaClass up = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
 AndroidJavaObject ca = up.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
```

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Thank you

Comment: Kill your own app, or another app?  Another app requires special permissions

Comment: Basically, I have two apps, App1 and App2. From the App1, I launch the App2, that works fine. And I would like to add a logic on App2 Start() function to force close App1

Comment: If you're launching app 2, why not have app 1 close itself after launching it?  That will be easier.  And are they actually 2 apps, or two activities (different things entirely)?

Comment: Can the App1 execute the launch command for App2 and then execute Application.Quit() ? Will the code still execute even after I launch the second app?

Comment: Yes, it will.  Launching an app doesn't stop the thread, it continues